# how to get interpolated data points from lables in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have data for Y and labels for X, but both are data. I move the mouse around my chart to get data at mouse x,y and the values from data are interpolated. i.e middle of 100 and 200 is 150. but the label data gives me an index. I can use the index to look up the label array but that is just a label, I need to interpolated the data. I could do this with math if the chart gave me the left most index of mouse x, but it gives my the closes index so math is not possible.

I'm using 2.9.4

### Fig. 1 for answer below.

- 
- 
- 
- ```
  . . .
  ```
- |_________ |_________ |_________ |_________

Comment: Chart.js doesn't have an API for interpolation, interpolation is only done internally to draw lines through points. On the other hand, you can typically get any kind of data from the chart and mouse, but it's currently not very clear what you have and what you need. Can you please post a working (code) example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: not  sure adding the project I have will help much but I can post it. but another way to illustrate my point it this. StackOV does not allow formatting so I added a chart above. There are 3 points. if I mouse over the first I get (index 1), if I mouse over the second I get (index 1 or 2) depending, if I mouse over the third I get (index2). If I could get index 1 all the time I could calculate what I need. Since I know the x,y at index 1 and I know the x,y at index 2 and my current x,y I can figure this all out. but it does not give me the left most index. always the  closest index.

Comment: We need to see the code. Show us what you tried to achieve what you are asking here and pinpoint why it is not working exactly. We cannot go off of just text and an illustration.

Comment: but in the shortest sense, I just want to know the data of x at mouse.  so if my data above for index 1 was 1, and index 2 was 20. I want.  2,5,8 for each respective dot.

Comment: @MonsteR was not sure if you meant the entire code or just the chart so I made a pastbin  https://pastebin.com/1wqxJ4Wp line 571 is where I tried to calculations. If I could get the frequency to me the data between the point, that would be my goal.